# Scala partially applied curried functions

Tags: scala, currying

Why can't i rewrite

```
println(abc.foldRight(0)((a,b) => math.max(a.length,b)))
```

in

```
object Main {
  def main(args : Array[String]) {
    val abc = Array[String]("a","abc","erfgg","r")
    println(abc.foldRight(0)((a,b) => math.max(a.length,b)))
  }
}
```

to

```
println(abc.foldRight(0)(math.max(_.length,_)))
```

? `scala` interpreter yields

```
/path/to/Main.scala:4: error: wrong number of parameters; expected = 2
    println(abc.foldRight(0)(math.max(_.length,_)))
                                     ^
one error found
```

Which is not descriptive enough for me. Isn't resulting lambda takes two parameters one of which being called for .length method, as in `abc.map(_.length)`?

Comment: Using two _ how will the compiler know which parameter to substitute for the first _ and second one from the a,b?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`abc.foldRight(0)(math.max(_.length, _))` will expand to something like `abc.foldRight(0)(y => math.max(x => x.length, y))`. The placeholder syntax expands in the nearest pair of closing parentheses, except when you have only the underscore in which case it will expand outside the closest pair of parentheses.

You can use `abc.foldRight(0)(_.length max _)` which doesn't suffer from this drawback.